# Count previous year on mySQL

Tags: mysql, count

I would like to show how many people registered in a certain month. Currently, I'm using this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM wp_users 
WHERE YEAR(user_registered)=YEAR(CURDATE()) 
     AND MONTH(user_registered)=MONTH(CURDATE()) - 2
```

For example, this code will count how many users registered 2 months ago. However, there is a problem when I try to make it 4 months ago or more. Basically, it doesn't take into account the previous year.

**** EDIT *****

I want it to display the count for one month only. For example only April, only March, Only February. The code that I'm using now works for months in year `2017` because I'm using `WHERE YEAR(user_registered) = YEAR(CURDATE())` but how can I make it work for the previous year also?

Comment: Show  HOW you "make it 4 months ago or more" - what did you attempt or is it just this `YEAR(CURDATE()}`

Comment: I just use the same code but use 4 instead of 2.

Comment: You DO realize that `YEAR(CURDATE())` is 2017 so prior to 4 months in that current year is NOT going to work given that this is the 4th month.  You need to get the prior year in that case...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this option:

```
 SELECT COUNT(0) 
 FROM wp_users 
 WHERE YEAR(user_registered)=YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH)) 
 AND MONTH(user_registered)= MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH))
```

Use DATE_SUB for made the subtraction.
[MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

Comment: This will give me a count of all 4 months before today. I want it to count months separately. For example only february or only january. Te problem occurs when I try to use previous year instead of the current year.

Comment: I think that you have to explain better your problem.. If you want the count separately you can add the `GROUP BY` clause, but I'm not sure If I understands your problem...

Comment: I want to count the number of users registered in March, February, January separetely.

Comment: It works fine for March February January, but fails to do it for December of the previous year because the year has to go back

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want a result for all the 12 month? A simple solution would be

```
SELECT MONTH(user_registered) as month, COUNT(*) FROM wp_users GROUP BY month;
```

However that would not return a row, if no one registered in a certain month. In order to do so, you would need to use a subquery, which returns the list from 1 to 12